# Eloquent: how to get values from a collection that are related to all items in a specified collection?

Tags: eloquent, relationship

I wasn't sure how to put in words of what I want to achieve so I will just demonstrate it with an example.

Let's say we have tags and objects. Tags and objects are related by a many to many relationship.
Example:

> Object1 has tags A, B and C.
> Object2 has tags A, D and E.
> Object3 has one tag - A.

I want to get all the tags that are found across all of these objects (in this example I specified 3, but there can be N amount of objects). The result should contain a collection of tags, where only tag A would be included because that is the only tag that can be found in all 3 objects.

How may I achieve this? An example using eloquent would be perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of research I finally found what I was looking for. It's called intersection and laravel has such method for collections.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-intersect

This is what I ended up with:

```
  $tags = Tag::whereHas('objects', function($q) use($request){
    return $q->whereIn('dynamic_abstract_objects.id', $request->input('objects', []));
  })->get(); //first we get all the tags that belong to all provided objects
  //then we iterate over each object to get it's tags
  foreach($request->input('objects', []) as $objectId){
    $objectTags = DynamicAbstractObject::where('id', $objectId)->first()->tags()->get();
    $intersection = $objectTags->intersect($tags);
    $tags = $intersection; //we assign intersection result for further loops
  }
  return $tags;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to query the tag-to-object relationship instead. By knowning the amount of objects you have, you can check in a foreach tag loop to find how many relations it has to objects. If it matches the number of objects, it is related to all. (This is assuming each tag-to-object relation is unique, which it should).

Comment: I actually thought of this way of solving it but I wanted to find something more elegant.